# How can I modify an MSI in memory?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, memorystream

I'd like to read an MSI file into a MemoryStream (or something similar), and modify it. What's the easiest way to do this, without corrupting the MSI?

All I need to be able to do is modify the value of one of the properties in the MSI. I'd prefer something in .Net, but I'm open to other platforms.

**Update:**

Here's my working code, using the Windows platform SDK, a COM reference to Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library and namespace WindowsInstaller:

```
Installer installer = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer")) as Installer;

Database msi = installer.OpenDatabase("WixTest.msi", MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);

View view = msi.OpenView("update `Property` SET `Property`.`Value`='99' where `Property`='USERID'");

view.Execute(null);

msi.Commit();
```

Comment: It's a little unclear when you mean to make this change. If it's before distributing the MSI, modifying it is probably okay. If it's after (or if it's an MSI you received from elsewhere), it's better to create a transform (or if the property is public, perhaps just modify it on the command line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370834(VS.85).aspx), there are a bunch of samples included on using the [Windows Installer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432(VS.85).aspx).

Here's a simplified version of a command line VBScript I use to do this:

```
Option Explicit


Const msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly     = 0
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact     = 1

Dim openMode : openMode = msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact

Dim argCount:argCount = Wscript.Arguments.Count

If (argCount < 3) Then  WScript.Echo "usage: msisetproperty.vbs <msi> <property> <value>" :     WScript.Quit 1

Dim MY_MSI : MY_MSI = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Dim sProp1 : sProp1 = Wscript.Arguments(1)
Dim sVal1  : sVal1 = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Dim filesys : Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not filesys.FileExists(MY_MSI) Then WScript.Echo "Unable to find msi, exiting" : WScript.Quit 1

Dim installer, database, view, result

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Dim sumInfo  : Set sumInfo = installer.SummaryInformation(MY_MSI, 0)

Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (MY_MSI, openMode)

Set view = database.OpenView ("UPDATE Property SET Value='" & sVal1 & "' WHERE Property='" & sProp1 & "'")
view.Execute

database.Commit
Set database = nothing
```

Comment: I've seen that before, and it does what I'd like to do. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out what references I need to add to my project. I have the Windows SDK installed (I'm donwloading the samples now), but I didn't see anything in its directory that jumped out at me.

Comment: I think I've found it. There's a COM reference called Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library, which as a WindowsInstaller namespace, which has the installer and database objects. Also, here's the guide I'm using to do it in C#: http://bit.ly/942ZZe. I'll report back when I get it working. Thanks for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post is really old, for the sake of users who happen to get here via search engines, there is a very neat .Net library which implements nearly all of the functionality of the Windows Installer SDK and is actively maintained by Rob Mensching, a senior developer at Microsoft. Its present in the Wix Toolset and you can get v3.6 RC0 [here.](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/85409)
After installing this toolset, add a reference to Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll present in the install directory of this toolset and you are good to go.
You can easily load the whole msi database into a DataSet and perform the required read/write operations and finally commit the changes to the msi.